# JavaScript "color variable undefined"

Tags: error-handling, syntax, scope, variable-assignment

I am running back an error of "color not defined" and possibly more. I run each block separately and they come back undefined. When I run the final piece basically executing the whole setup I get this error.

```
function consoleStyler(color, background, fontSize, txt) {
var message = "%c" + txt;
var style = `color: ${color};`
style += `background: ${background};`
style += `font-size: ${fontSize};`
console.log(style);
console.log(message);
 }

function celebrateStyler(reason) {
var fontStyle = "color: tomato; font-size: 50px";
if (reason == "birthday") {
    console.log(`%cHappy birthday`, fontStyle);
} else if (reason == "champions") {
    console.log(`%cCongrats on the title!`, fontStyle);
} else {
    console.log(message, style);
}
}

consoleStyler('#1d5c63', '#ede6db', '40px', 'Congrats!');
celebrateStyler('birthday');

function styleAndCelebrate() {
    consoleStyler(color, background, fontSize, txt)
    celebrateStyler(reason)
}
styleAndCelebrate('ef7c8e', 'fae8e0', '30px', 'You made it!', 'champions');
```

Comment: You have not defined the functions parameter in function declaration of styleAndCelebrate. You need to do function styleAndCelebrate(color, background, fontSize, txt, reason) {//function body}

Comment: The styleAndCelebrate function has no parameters defined..

Comment: Question formatting needs some work too

Comment: Thank you @MuhammadHamidRafique for the help. I have been trying to learn on Coursera and their instructions are not helpful to say the least. They also teach you alot about x and a little about y but then expect you to put x and y together. I have never learned these %c notations or background, colors codes but they put it in homework. Would this program run correctly as is now after adding parameters? It still doesn't seem right like my values for color and background should actually output the font with color etc and not just the code I typed in.

Comment: You need to pass in the style as the parameter to the log function. So, in consoleStyler, you would need to do `console.log(message, style)` if you want to customize the console output. It also depends on where you are running this since, it could be up to the browser as to what it supports.